# SELECT INTO localVariable more then one row

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure() BEGIN
    DECLARE tmp DECIMAL(8,2) ;
    SELECT cip.modifier * cip.price * COALESCE(CAST(cip.quantity AS SIGNED), 1) INTO tmp FROM customerInvoicePosition cip...
    SELECT SUM(tmp * (if(cip.type=0,1,0))) FROM customerInvoicePosition cip...
    SELECT SUM(tmp * (if(cip.type=1,1,0))) FROM customerInvoicePosition cip...
    SELECT SUM(tmp * (if(cip.type=2,1,0))) FROM customerInvoicePosition cip...
    SELECT SUM(tmp * (if(cip.type=3,1,0))) FROM customerInvoicePosition cip...
    END;
```

Error: Result consisted of more than one row

OK, I understand error message, but is there some solution to store more then one row in a variable/list?

Comment: No, use a (temporary) table.

Comment: Like this:
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp AS (SELECT  cip.modifier * cip.price * COALESCE(CAST(cip.quantity AS SIGNED), 1)  FROM customerInvoicePosition cip...)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [cursor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) - I'd give an example but since your code doesn't do anything meaningful its impossible to advise.

Looking at your code, it might even be appropriate to create a view rather than using a (semi-?)temporary table (although there advantages to the latter approach, particularly if the data can persist across sessions).

Actually, it might be possible to describe the functionality in a single select statement (what's left of the code here is very innefficient) but again you've mangled the code to the point of removing any meaning from it.

Comment: Before this end;

There is a part: 

INSERT INTO newTable (param1, param2, param3, param4)  SELECT 
SUM(tmp * (if(cip.type=0,1,0))) , 
SUM(tmp * (if(cip.type=1,1,0))) ,
SUM(tmp * (if(cip.type=2,1,0))) ,
SUM(tmp * (if(cip.type=3,1,0))) FROM customerInvoicePosition cip...
end;